# Flexbox: How to stretch row's elements to full width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox grid of random width images:

[image]

I would like to stretch elements of each row to full width in order to get rid of white-space - how can I achieve that with CSS?
`justify-content` doesn't seem to help much. I have read about some JavaScript techniques but I would like to avoid it if possible.

**[Edited] Expected result**: [example](https://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/example.html)

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grid .grid-item {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: none;
  margin: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid .grid-item .grid-in {
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 190px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.grid img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-in">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? The white-space on the third row right is your problem?

Comment: You have on  `.grid .grid-in .grid-item ` a margin of 1px. Maybe you should remove it

Comment: @ManojKumar: I have added a code snippet to the question. **Luis**: Removing margin doesn't help.

Comment: If you don't care about the size of margins in between the images that is to say the goal is to maintain the smooth square-like container you could try using `justify-content: space-between`

Comment: I also recommend you go through and watch [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg), it'll take around 30mins and you'll be a pro at flex afterward :P

Comment: Are you expecting the images to stretch...I'm unclear as to what the final result should look like..with images in it.

Comment: that's correct, I expect images to proportionally stretch, so that the grid content would be justified and without any white-space

Comment: I'm interested in result as in following example: https://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/example.html

Answer (score 0):

First wrap every row in an container, say `.grid-row`, which will have those Flexbox properties you previously assigned to `.grid`.

Now set `flex-grow` property for each cell, the value can be anything, as long as the **ratio** of the values per row is correct. You can simply set it to the width of the cell (without the unit), so the first cell will have `flex-grow: 190`. Also, make sure to set `flex-shrink` to `1` on all `.grid-item`s to avoid [this flexbug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#6-the-default-flex-value-has-changed).

To make the images stretch all the way, remove all that `inline-block` business from the `.grid-in`. And to make them proportionally increase height, instead of being cropped to `190px`, remove `width: 190px` from `.grid-in`.

Finally, to space them out, in this case it's better to use `padding: 1px` on `.grid-item` instead of `margin: 1px` on `.grid-in`.

Because the demo wasn't reduced enough, I cleaned it for the sake of clarity. Hopefully you'll know how to implement it in your original code.

```css
.grid-row {
  display: flex;
}

.grid-item {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 1px;
}

.grid-row:nth-child(1) .grid-item:nth-child(1) { flex-grow: 190; }
.grid-row:nth-child(1) .grid-item:nth-child(2) { flex-grow: 250; }
.grid-row:nth-child(1) .grid-item:nth-child(3) { flex-grow: 100; }

.grid-row:nth-child(2) .grid-item:nth-child(1) { flex-grow: 190; }
.grid-row:nth-child(2) .grid-item:nth-child(2) { flex-grow: 250; }
.grid-row:nth-child(2) .grid-item:nth-child(3) { flex-grow: 190; }

.grid-row:nth-child(3) .grid-item:nth-child(1) { flex-grow: 100; }
.grid-row:nth-child(3) .grid-item:nth-child(2) { flex-grow: 190; }
.grid-row:nth-child(3) .grid-item:nth-child(3) { flex-grow: 250; }

.grid-row:nth-child(4) .grid-item:nth-child(1) { flex-grow: 190; }
.grid-row:nth-child(4) .grid-item:nth-child(2) { flex-grow: 100; }
.grid-row:nth-child(4) .grid-item:nth-child(3) { flex-grow: 190; }

.grid img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-in">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow that is some solution, but I'm afraid it's against the idea of flexbox and rwd...

Comment: I agree. I edited my answer to use a more elegant and Flexboxy solution, if you're ok with adding a container around rows ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled across this issue and unfortunately couldn't solve it using Flexbox. 
The answer might suprise you, but what I found to be the appropriate solution for me here is a table, yeah you heard me right, a `<table>`!

There are a couple of constraints to keep in mind:

1. You should know the numbers of cells / columns you want on each row.
2. In the case where columns have different widths on every row, you'll need a table element for every row. ('member 2000s?)

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x190" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use other html elements and mimic the table behaviour using css
`display: table | table-row | table-cell`